# Running CreateFile Win32 interop as a standard user

Tags: c#, .net, permissions

I need to access an external physical drive using the Win32 CreateFile() method as described here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/100027.

It states you must be an administrator but I want to run the application as a standard user. Does anyone know a way of allowing this?. I have considered Impersonation or creating a service, but it would be better if I could elevate permissions for a specific user account.

Comment: Since the application needs direct disk access why not run it as an administrator?

Comment: I can't run the application as an Administrator in the target environment, hence the question!.

Comment: You should be able to do it with a cmd.exe process.  First open a cmd.exe window a see if you can get to folder by typing >cd \\servername.  Win32 is  an application that originally ran under Win95 and cmd.exe is also a Win95 application.  So open a process make the appliaction cmd.exe and then the execuatable as a parameter.  Sma e as example on following page but replace HelloWorld.exe with cmd.exe.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already running the console application via the command prompt already. The application tries to access a Physical drive, which needs to use \\.\PhysicalDriveN via CreateFile().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible as a standard user, but I was able to solve the issue I had by wrapping the CreateFile request in a WCF Service, and hosting locally within a Windows Service.

The Windows Service can use Local System credentials, which has elevated permissions, and allows access to the Win32 CreateFile function. See [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) for details.

I can then add a service reference to my console project, and call the service method. This also means I did not have to change any user inputs, which was one of my requirements.

See [Host a WCF Service in a Managed Windows Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069(v=vs.110).aspx) for information on how to host a WCF Service in a Windows Service.

Comment: When you do this, make very sure the WCF service only offers local bindings. Presumably you can control everything that runs on the machine (if even this is not true, add authentication as well). Furthermore, rather than using "Local System" (which can do even *more* than administrators out of the box) consider using a dedicated local account that you add to the administrators group instead. If anything bad happens through the service, this aids in auditing.

Comment: I've set the WCF service to use local bindings on a specific port. I assume you mean I could use [NetNamedPipeBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding.aspx)?.  I'm using Active Directory to authenticate the user, and they have to belong to specific group. I have set up a dedicated Admin account for the service as you suggested, thanks.

Comment: The exact binding type doesn't matter, as long as the endpoint (I should have said "endpoint" and not "binding") is only accessible from the machine itself and not from the outside. `NetNamedPipeBinding` is a good choice because it doesn't support communication from outside the machine anyway; an HTTP or TCP binding must be explicitly configured to work this way.